# Understanding a REGEX Quirk in using \S in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm refreshing my long lost knowlege of regex in Java Script and cannot fathom this.

As I recall \S means not white space and \D means not a number. These are the counterpart to the lower case alternatives which would search for a space or a number. respectively.

Search for the first non numeric charter that does not have white space either side
Code:

```
var digitSurroundedBySpace = /\S\D\S/;
document.writeln("1234567AB".search(digitSurroundedBySpace));
```

this returns 6. Which is not what I expect. It seems the mere presence of the first \S thows the answer off by one.

Search for the first non numeric charter that does not have white space after it.

```
var digitSurroundedBySpace = /\D\S/;
document.writeln("1234567AB".search(digitSurroundedBySpace));
```

this returns 7 which I expect.

Should they not both return a 7. Why does the first one not?

Comment: a "digit surrounded by space" would be /\s\d\s/ instead of /\S\D\S/ ... "7AB" starts 6 chars in and matches /\S\D\S/ because you have a non-space, then a non-digit, then a non-space. as "A" is the first hit for just a non-digit, the 2nd example starts at char 7

Comment: From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search): *"If successful, search returns the **index** of the regular expression inside the string. Otherwise, it returns -1."*

Comment: @dandavis. Sorry I meant does not have white space either side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused by the characters in the string versus the index position of those characters in the string. The first match is at `7AB`. The `7` is character number 6 in the string, because we start counting from 0. Thus, your `.search()` returns 6, the correct offset of `7AB`.

```
var digitSurroundedBySpace = /\S\D\S/;
document.writeln("1234567AB".search(digitSurroundedBySpace));
//  index:        012345678
//  match:              ^

var digitSurroundedBySpace = /\D\S/;
document.writeln("1234567AB".search(digitSurroundedBySpace));
//  index:        012345678
//  match:               ^
```

Comment: Oh my goodness you are so right. It's obvious now you say it.